# Cassandra doesn't imply particular order in which the statements are executed

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, erlang

Cassandra doesn't imply particular order in which the statements are executed.

Executing statements like the code below doesn't execute in the order.

```
INSERT INTO channel 
        JSON ''{"cuid":"NQAA0WAL6drA"
                ,"owner":"123"
                ,"status":"open"
                ,"post_count":0
                ,"mem_count":1
                ,"link":"FWsA609l2Og1AADRYODkzNjE2MTIyOTE="
                , "create_at":"1543328307953"}}'';

BEGIN BATCH 

UPDATE channel 
    SET title = ? , description = ?  WHERE cuid = ? ;
INSERT INTO channel_subscriber 
    JSON ''{"cuid":"NQAA0WAL6drA"
            ,"user_id":"123"
            ,"status":"subscribed"
            ,"priority":"owner"
            ,"mute":false
            ,"setting":{"create_at":"1543328307956"}}'';

APPLY BATCH ;
```

According to system_traces.sessions each of them are received by different nodes.

Sometimes the `started_at` time in both query are equal (in milliseconds), sometimes the `started_at` time of second query is less than the first one.
So, this ruins the order of statements and data.

We use erlang, marina driver, consistency_level is QUORUM and time of all cassandra nodes and application server are sync.

How can I force Cassandra to execute queries in order?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the distributed nature, queries in Cassandra could be received by different nodes, and depending on the load on particular node, it could be that some queries that sent later, are executed earlier.  In your case you can put first insert into batch itself. Or, as it's implemented in some drivers (for example, [Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/load_balancing/#filtering-policies)), use whitelist policy to send queries to only one node - but it will be bottleneck in this case.  (and I really not sure that your driver has such functionality).

Comment: Adding to that - you should not execute statements for different partitions in same batch, this is a clear anti pattern (see https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html, and in further depth - http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2015/02/cassandra-anti-pattern-misuse-of.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should mentioned that I send second query(batch) after get ack of first query. created_at column show that they sent in different time.

Comment: @LiorChaga According to their own timestamp in JSON, they've get QUORUM ack for 1st query and after spending 3 milliseconds they've send 2nd query. I could not find any point in posts you mentioned that this can result something like he/she said ! Am I wrong?

Comment: what I suggested is that when you include in your batch 2 statements from different partitions, with very high probability these statements would be carried out by different nodes. That is - the coordinator would propagate 1st statements to nodes X, Y, Z, and 2nd statement to nodes U,V,W. Nothing guarantees that 1st statement would be actually carried out and acked before 2nd.

Comment: As I see from queries, the `cuid` is partition key, and in batch all have the same value

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes, cuid is partition key.

Comment: @AlexOtt ,@LiorChaga we have just three nodes with Replication factor=3 and   consistency level = QUORUM. Cassadra guaranteed that it should be read and write at least on two nodes then confirm that write is done.